# Getting 404 error for every page with python socket

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, http-status-code-404, port

I started to learn python. I was trying this piece of code from the book.

```
import socket

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    mysock.connect(('www.py4inf.com', 80))
    mysock.send('GET http://www.py4inf.com/code/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n')

except Exception as e:
    print(e)


try:
    while True:
        data = mysock.recv(512)
        if ( len(data) < 1 ) :
            break
        print data  
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

mysock.close()
```

It doesn't matter which web page I am trying to connect, I am getting 404 error.
I got the following when I run the code.

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 23 May 2017 17:54:54 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 162
Connection: close

<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try using `GET /code/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\nHost: www.py4inf.com\n\n`

Comment: It worked!. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
mysock.send('GET http://www.py4inf.com/code/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n')
```

You are trying to send a HTTP request but there are multiple things wrong with it. Some of these cause problems while others just get ignored by this specific server:

- The line end should be `\r\n` not `\n`
- The path in the GET request should not be an absolute URL but relative to the server, i.e. `/code/romeo.txt`. Absolute is acceptable with HTTP/1.1 but you use HTTP/1.0.
- The server uses virtual hosting, i.e. multiple host names on the same IP address. Therefore you must specify which host to access using a `Host` header.

The last item is actually the most important one in this case but the other points should be fixed too. Thus the correct request would look like this

```
mysock.send('GET /code/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: www.py4inf.com\r\n\r\n')
```

For more information please study the HTTP standard, i.e. [RFC 1945](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945) for the simpler HTTP/1.0 and [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) for HTTP/1.1 which is more complex but more used in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line`mysock.send('GET http://www.py4inf.com/code/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n')`  use this instead `mysock.connect(('www.py4inf.com', 80))
                mysock.send('GET /code/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\nHost:www.py4inf.com\n\n'.encode())`

the connection should look like this :

`import socket` 


    `mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)`
    `mysock.connect(('www.py4inf.com', 80))`


    `mysock.send('GET /code/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\nHost:www.py4inf.com\n\n'.encode())`

```
while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if (len(data) < 1):
        break
    print(data.decode(),end='')

mysock.close()
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here i made the change for you hope this will help :

**Ps:** also on line 19 `Print (data)` or you will get SyntaxError

```
import socket

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    mysock.connect(('www.py4inf.com', 80))
    #mysock.send('GET http://www.py4inf.com/code/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n')
    mysock.send('GET /code/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\nHost:www.py4inf.com\n\n'.encode())

except Exception as e:
    print(e)


try:
    while True:
        data = mysock.recv(512)
        if ( len(data) < 1 ) :
            break
        print (data)  
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

mysock.close()
```